# Id filed in SOLR is diferrent from URL when crawled by nutch for redirected URLs

Tags: redirect, nutch

I am using nutch 1.13 and SOLR 5.5
majority of the time the URL field = ID field when nutch index documents in SOLR
but i have seen cases when ID is different from URL field and it happens when the URL1 is redirected to URL 2 and URL2 is fetched 
there are two scenarios

1st scenario (id not equals URL ) the [https://www.givaudan.com/files/giv-2018-integrated-annual-report.pdf(*repr*](https://www.givaudan.com/files/giv-2018-integrated-annual-report.pdf(_repr_) metadata) is used as URL and https://www.givaudan.com/file/149296/download as ID in solr

```
https://www.givaudan.com/files/giv-2018-integrated-annual-report.pdf     
Version: 7
Status: 4 (db_redir_temp)
Fetch time: Thu Mar 07 07:18:53 UTC 2019
Modified time: Tue Feb 05 07:18:53 UTC 2019
Retries since fetch: 0
Retry interval: 2592000 seconds (30 days)
Score: 0.0013103343
Signature: 989b82c1e6e738b74f36d64534f95050
Metadata: 
_pst_=temp_moved(13), lastModified=0: 
https://www.givaudan.com/file/149296/download
_rs_=2508
Content-Type=text/html
nutch.protocol.code=302




https://www.givaudan.com/file/149296/download   Version: 7
Status: 2 (db_fetched)
Fetch time: Thu Mar 07 07:19:08 UTC 2019
Modified time: Tue Feb 05 07:19:08 UTC 2019
Retries since fetch: 0
Retry interval: 2592000 seconds (30 days)
Score: 0.0029494818
Signature: 7ecff30181eb4268cfb1dd0b79df7e8a
Metadata: 
_repr_=https://www.givaudan.com/files/giv-2018-integrated-annual-report.pdf
_pst_=success(1), lastModified=1549351146000
_rs_=14411
Content-Type=application/pdf
nutch.protocol.code=200
```

2nd scenario(id is same as URL ) there is no repr metadata

```
https://www.givaudan.com/files/giv-2017-annual-report.pdf   Version: 7
Status: 4 (db_redir_temp)
Fetch time: Thu Mar 07 07:18:14 UTC 2019
Modified time: Tue Feb 05 07:18:14 UTC 2019
Retries since fetch: 0
Retry interval: 2592000 seconds (30 days)
Score: 0.0012841906
Signature: e47ac79e3f75007a0c89490e7e2bbdbd
Metadata: 
_pst_=temp_moved(13), lastModified=0: 
https://www.givaudan.com/file/86431/download
_rs_=2537
Content-Type=text/html
nutch.protocol.code=302


https://www.givaudan.com/file/86431/download    Version: 7
Status: 2 (db_fetched)
Fetch time: Thu Mar 07 07:19:46 UTC 2019
Modified time: Tue Feb 05 07:19:46 UTC 2019
Retries since fetch: 0
Retry interval: 2592000 seconds (30 days)
Score: 5.633987E-4
Signature: 03a2542baa11916676f438c662e58b2e
Metadata: 
_pst_=success(1), lastModified=1549350016000
_rs_=5620
Content-Type=application/pdf
nutch.protocol.code=200
```

what does repr metada tag indicates
are only db_fetched status url indexed?
currently i am using URL to search document from SOLR which works fine for majority of the urls but few edge cases like the above and i don't get any result for https://www.givaudan.com/file/149296/download
should i use ID instead of URL to fetch data from SOLR , will that create any issues

Answer (score 0):

Nutch can by design only index documents under the URL they have been successfully fetched (HTTP status 200). In your example that's the URLs endingin in `.../download`. For redirects there are [some heuristics](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.13/org/apache/nutch/util/URLUtil.html#chooseRepr-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-) to find the most representative URL, in the first example `https://www.givaudan.com/files/giv-2017-annual-report.pdf` is selected as `_repr_` URL over `https://www.givaudan.com/file/149296/download` (to my opinion not a bad choice). However, the heuristics does not work if the redirect target URL is found earlier as an ordinary link or has been injected as seed.

> should I use ID instead of URL to fetch data from SOLR

Yes, because it will not change. But you may use the "url" field to be displayed as link on the search result page.